# Bootstrap Div fill parent height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a container that has 2 `div`s, the first one needs to keeps its height in relation to the content inside of it, for example, text, and the other one needs to fill its parent height no matter if there is content or not inside it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" id="column">
        <div id="column-name" class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">TEXT</div>
        <div class="card-list col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 " id="card-list-1">
            <!-- here are divs that fill this card-list up -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`#column` is the `div` that contains the other 2 `div`s. I want `#column-name` to change its height based on the content(in this case, only the text inside), but I want `#card-list-1` to fill the rest of the `#column`s height, event though there is no content inside. `#column` resizes itself with the rest of the columns in the page, so it's height must not be handled at all.
I tried using `flex`, but for some reason, the `#column-name` and `#card-list-1` both resize the same amount, that is twice the height of the parent.
This is the `css`:

```
#column{
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 2px;

}

#column-name{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    height: 18px;
}

.card-list{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;  
}
```

This is actually part of a design that has 4 columns, and `div`s are being drag-and-dropped inside of the 'card-list's.
I'd really prefer a `css` or `bootstrap` solution, so it can be used also on mobile platform.
Thanks.

EDIT:
If I use the `flex:1` on `#card-list-1`, I end up with this result:
Before [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8C77.png)
After [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vubik.png)

Also a link to the code of the problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyrrvZ

Comment: a note ; you don't need all this `col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` using `col-xs-12` is enough in your case

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use flex and column direction. In both of them you are using `col-*-12` so you want them to be full width and this will be done with the column direction so you can also ommit those classes. Then simply make the second one `flex:1` so it takes the remaining spaces:

```css
#column {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 300px; /*added a height to illustrate*/
  display: flex; /* new */
  flex-direction:column; /* new */
}

#column-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  height: 18px;
}

.card-list {
  flex: 1; /* new */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-3" id="column">
  <div id="column-name">TEXT</div>
  <div class="card-list" id="card-list-1">
    <!-- here are divs that fill this card-list up -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When a `div` inside `card-list` changes it's `height`(this is triggered by a button, on itself), the `column-name` resizes to the original `column` height, and also `card-list` does that, so I end up with 2 `div`s inside the parent that combined have double the size of the parent.

Comment: @Justplayit are you able to show me this code working ? as i can do nothing if i don't see the whole thing

Comment: Sorry for the wait, this is some of the code, just press where it says `PRESS ME`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyrrvZ

Comment: @Justplayit you didn't remove the classes as i said in the answer :) you no more need to specify the classe since we used column direction

Comment: Oh, wow, this is it. So remove all the `col-*` classes is the answer. Thanks.